# Finding/deleting top level folders not containing any files

Tags: linux, bash, find, recursive

I want to delete the top level directory which does not contain any files, but can contain other empty (meaning again not containing files) directories. For example:

```
$ ls -R
.: foo/
./foo/: bar  bar1
./foo/bar/:
./foo/bar1/:
```

Here, I would like to delete the directory `foo/` (and its subdirectories).
At first, I thought of using something like `find . -type d -empty` for the search, but since foo contains directories, it only finds the lower level ones:

```
$ find . -type d -empty
./foo/bar
./foo/bar1
```

I guess I could loop until `find . -type d -empty` finds nothing, but I may end up having a very big directory structure containing a lot of those empty directories and I'm concerned about the performance impact of doing it that way...

Any idea?

Comment: I think they're discussing something similar to this in this question too: http://serverfault.com/questions/197785/list-all-empty-folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find . -depth -type d -empty` should do the trick.  `-depth` will cause find to process a directory's contents before the directory itself.

**Edit:**

Presumably you'd be using something like `-delete` at the end of this find, else you'd have the same problem you described.  Also worth noting, `-delete` actually implies `-depth`, so really, sticking with `find . -type d -empty -delete` would give you what you're looking for in one pass; presuming you have no problem deleting any other lower level empty directories you encounter as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. find . -depth -type d -empty -delete worked for me as expected. Will definitly remember that -depth parameter for other uses. Thanks

Comment: I.e., even if `find . -type d -empty` doesn't return `foo` adding `-delete` does work. It checks if `foo` is empty after it has deleted `bar` and `bar1` and thus it would delete `foo`.